# ScrolledComposite splits the screen vertically and content is displayed in the right half

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, scrolledcomposite

I am using the ScrolledComposite for a existing control(with many children) based on the method2 mentioned here :http://www.placelab.org/toolkit/doc/javadoc/org/placelab/util/swt/SwtScrolledComposite.html

The only change is instead of creating a new shell & display I am using the existing control's parent.
I am seeing the scroll bars as expected but the existing control/content is displayed form the centre & not from the start. The first half(vertically split) of the layout is empty & the actual control/content gets displayed in the right-half.
I checked bounds, Origin, size etc. they seem to be fine.

screenshot putup here :http://img818.imageshack.us/i/contentstartsfrommiddle.jpg

Any clues

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the Composite `c1`? maybe that is in the left side.

You could also provide what is exactly your change to the code.

Comment: I think I got the problem. To the existing parent control an empty composite was getting added this is causing the problem. Once I removed the composite creation code to appropriate place things look fine.